# Unable to create a new Task for progress bar in Java FX

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have created a progress bar in mine Java FXML controller UI and passing the values to it thru executeWSButton. I am creating the new task in createWorker() Method and binding the property value to the progress bar.

The issue is now I am not able to create new Task() in createWorker() method.It was working fine 6 month back and I have resumed the development work . Could you please suggest what could be possible reason here

```
@FXML
public void executeWSButton(ActionEvent event) {
    outputTextScreen.appendText(newLine + " Execution for Process:  Started" + newLine);

    executeWS.setDisable(true);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    copyWorker = createWorker();
    if(testModule != "") {
        progressBar.progressProperty().unbind();
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(copyWorker.progressProperty());
        new Thread(copyWorker).start();
        executeWS.setDisable(false);
    }
    else {
        outputTextScreen.appendText(" Execution for Process: " + Item + " do not have any current TestMethods to Call, Hence stopping the test" + newLine);

    }
}


public Task createWorker() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {

                Invoke_TestNG_Classes ws = new Invoke_TestNG_Classes();
                String output = ws.iterateThroughTestCases(inputfile_fp, GIfile_fp, testModule,excelPath);
                if(output.contains("Mark atleast"))
                {
                    updateProgress(1.0, 1.0);
                    outputTextScreen.appendText(
                            "Please mark atleast one test case with flag as Y in Testcase Execution sheet for "+ Item + newLine);
                    textOutput.setText("Test Execution Aborted");
                                        return true;
                }
                while (output.contains("Completed")) {
                    updateProgress(1.0, 1.0);
                    // progressBar.setAccessibleText("Completed");
                    System.out.println(output);
                    outputTextScreen.appendText("Webservice Execution for Process: " + Item + " Completed" + newLine);

                    textOutput.setText("Test Execution Completed");
                    return true;

                }
                return true;
            }

        };
    }
```

Comment: This worked 6 months ago?`String`s shouldn't be compared using`!=`, but using `equals`+negation(or in this case assuming`testModule`is non-`null` `isEmpty()`).  The`while`loop shouldn't be a`while`loop,but an `if`(The values involved in the check are never modified in the loop which would result in an infinite loop,if the conditon was true if not for the return, which could simply be removed,if an`if`statement was used instead of the loop).The actual issue though seems to be the fact that you're using`setProgress`before unbinding the property which should result in"a bound value cannot be set"

Comment: return new Task() is not creating a new task in createWorker method . The call not new Task() is returning with error